# Way to high Solve Error or it is not accurate with the refined trackers

Tags: tracking

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QMxlkSUBC7DmkSHE9jBvEyLbQaWrqh8A/view?usp=sharing)

I tracked the thing and I do not think, that I tracked it so badly that the solve error should be 255.86. And before I wanted to change some things I had a Solve Error of about 1.03 but in a real scene I was not able to use it because it shook really bad.

I stumbled upon a post of refined tracks and mine are way of where they should be. I really do not know why, cause I think I didn't make that bad of a job.

Comment: before uploading your blend file, you should do this: file -> external data -> pack all into blend file

Comment: the footage is not visible, as its not included in the .blend file... you should first do what the previous comment said

Comment: I made a new question with the right link